# How to make a job (thread or deamon) in codeigniter

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter

I am writing an auction system.
I want to create(start) a job (thread or deamon) and after `N` minute called another function and this job will be destroyed.

for example:

[image]

These jobs will create when I want to.
Their number may be more than 200 per second.

Is there any library to do this? any

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, First, you need to write one method in your controller. In this method you need to process data that you want.

After that you need to schedule this method using cron job. You can access your method via command line.
ie.
`> php /var/www/html/index.php controller/method param1 param2`